# Ada - Discrete_Random example

Tags: ada

Page 53 of "Programming in Ada 2012" by John Barnes shares an incomplete fragment of code that I cannot get to work.

I've come up with this as a full program expanding the code from the book...

```
with Ada.Numerics; use Ada.Numerics;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
  type Coin is (Heads, Tails);
  package Random_Coin is new Discrete_Random(Coin);
  use Random_Coin;

  G : Generator;
  C : Coin;
begin

  for i in 1 .. 20 loop
    C := Random(G);
    Put (C'Image);
  end loop;  

end Main;
```

The "GPS" IDE I'm using complains of the following errors:

- Line 6: "Discrete_Random" is undefined
- Line 7: "Random_Coin" is undefined
- Line 9: "Generator" is undefined
- Line 14: "Random" is undefined

The IDE does give me the "intellisense" (to use a term from Visual Studio) that indicates that Discrete_Random is actually visible and available given the "with" and "use" statements I've added.

Can someone walk me through the stupid mistakes I'm making please?

Comment: `with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;`

Comment: p.s. what are people's opinions of this book?  I'm having real problems learning Ada, using this as the main reference.

Comment: @egilhh, I've tried a few variations, none of them work, although sometimes it changes from "undefined" to "not visible".

Comment: @Wossname egilh just told you what is the correct name for that package. See https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12aarm/html/AA-A-5-2.html for definition of those packages.

Comment: @darkestkhan, I realise that, I consulted the ALRM before posting the question, but still the code will not compile.  Why not create an answer using the above code as a starting point and I'll upvote and accept. :)

Comment: So it appears that it is necessary to have both `with Ada.Numerics; use Ada.Numerics;` and
`with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;` at the same time.  This was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, unlike `Ada.Numerics.Pi`, in which `Pi` is a component of `Ada.Numerics`, `Discrete_Random` is a child of `Ada.Numerics`.

Once you’ve said `use Ada.Numerics`, you could write just `Pi` in your program, but you have to actually `with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random` in order for it to be available.

In fact, you don’t need to `with` or `use` `Ada.Numerics`, this works just fine:

```
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Coin is (Heads, Tails);
   package Random_Coin is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Coin);
```